# Mockito argument matcher that matches any of a type with generics, excluding nulls

Tags: java, mockito

Lets say I've got a class like this

```
public class Wrapper<T> {
    T data;
}
```

And I have a method call like this:

```
public interface ThingDoer {
     <T> boolean doSomething(Wrapper<T> wrapper)
}
```

which I want to mock out in a test. Lets say we're all set up with the mockito stuff, and now I'm trying to mock out this method call

```
when(thingDoer.doSomething(any(Wrapper.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

However, this will give me a warning: `Unchecked assignment: 'package.Wrapper' to 'package.Wrapper<T>'`

I read another suggestion somewhere that with Java 8, you're supposed to use `any()` instead of `any(Wrapper.class)`. However, reading through the documentation on these two methods, `any()` will accept null arguments and `any(Class)` will reject null arguments, so they are not quite synonymous. Is there a way to exclude nulls without getting a warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isNotNull()`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#isNotNull--) as the matcher.

```
when(thingDoer.doSomething(isNotNull())).thenReturn(true);
```

Comment: Hmmm... looking through the docs, it looks like you're right. It's kind of a shame, I like the visibility of having the class name there to make it clear looking at the test immediately what the type is. This answers the question though, so thank you.

Comment: This works ONLY if doSomething() is not overloaded.

Comment: If there's an overload of `doSomething` which takes one reference-typed argument, you just need to add a type witness, e.g. `ArgumentMatchers.<SomeSpecificType>isNotNull()`.